# Does AC-3 algorithm decide a CSP?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

If AC-3 algorithm returns an empty domain, we know for sure it cannot be solved. But given that it returns only domains with at least a variable in it, do we know the CSP is solvable?

Comment: Try running it on $(x \oplus y = 0) \land (x \oplus y = 1)$.